# Drop columns according to some criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

For example, I have a dataframe called dat, then I want to apply a function on each column of the dataframe, if the return value is Ture, then keep this column and turn to next column, if the return value is False, then drop this column and turn to next column.

I know I can write a for loop to do this, but is there a efficient way to do this?

Comment: Is it the same function for each column, or does each column have a unique function?

Comment: Yep, same function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this using boolean index on df.columns:

I want to drop all columns where the 'sum' for simplicity is greater than 50

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,4,6,8],'B':[101,102,102,102]})

r = df.apply(np.sum) # applies the sum function to all columns

c = r <= 50 #create boolean test for columns

df[c[c].index] #Use boolea indexing to get columns and column filter for dataframe
```

Output:

```
   A
0  2
1  4
2  6
3  8
```

---

Updating an old answer:

```
df.loc[:, df.sum() <= 50]
```